# Weird Quest PowerShell error

Tags: powershell

"Move-QADObject : 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007EF, data 0, 1 access points"

I get this error when I try the following:

```
Move-QADObject -identity $results_ep.dn -NewParentContainer "OU=Users,OU=AB,DC=domain,DC=local" -Credential $cred_ep
```

I am running this script from domain A, and the target domain where the object should be moving is domain B (hence the credentials).

Anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 0):

The default tree in Active Directory is not `OU=Users,dc=domain,dc=com` but rather `cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com` ( `CN=` not the `OU=` for Users).

Try change `OU=Users` with `CN=Users`

EDIT:

Reading better your question I see just now that you want move object to a different domain,
from `get-help move-qadobject`:

... omissis ...
Use this cmdlet to move an object between containers within an Active Directory domain (**the cmdlet cannot move an object to a different domain**).
... omissis ...

Read [here](http://communities.quest.com/docs/DOC-10108) to do it with Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement sanp-in.

If you are in a `Windows Server 2008 R2` DC you can move in a different domain using Windows PowerShell module named `Active Directory`:

```
Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=Mary Vick,OU=Accounting,DC=SS64,DC=com" -TargetPath "OU=Accounting,DC=Europe,DC=SS64,DC=com" -TargetServer "server64.europe.SS64.com"
```

Better of all I think is using native Microsoft commandline like [`ADMT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: did not work :( "Move-QADObject : 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007EF, data 0, 1 access points
    ref 1: 'domain.local'"